# In Rails How to show the images of public folder on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I  use carrierwave to load images in public folder, it's ok on development environment,but  is error on production environment.

I tried change the `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `true`,but the bootstrap and js can't use. So I can't change the line.

This log shows error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/photo/cc/55/large_cc55a8a500951a2c9390ec8246179830.jpg")
```

But I have the image on the folder.

How to show the images on production,the quenstion have tortured me for seven days.
Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you try to set    config.assets.digest = false in production?

Comment: I did ,but there is nothing to show